# How to write basic lines in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and going through a "Beginning Programming" book.  It lists the following code to write basic lines on a website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>This is a Test</h1>

<script>

document.write("<p>I like to code</p>");
document.write("<p>I will succeed at coding</p>");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, the line

```
document.write("<p>I like to code</p>");
```

does not give the desired output of "I like to code" written on the website.

How should this be written to get this output?

Comment: and what the result it gave?

Comment: It works for me in Firefox, Chrome, and Opera.  All three lines of text are displayed.  Is it possible that Javascript is disabled in your browser?

Comment: Are you thinking of printing "<p>I like to code</p>" instead of "I like to code"?

Comment: Mars, yes, it works in Google Chrome but not in Explorer.  JS is probably disabled in my Explorer.  How do I enable JS in Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be running fine.  Try updating your HTML file to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>This is a Test</h1>
        <script>
            document.write("<p>I like to code</p>");
            document.write("<p>I will succeed at coding</p>");
        </script>
        <noscript>
            Javascript is disabled!
        </noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

and if you see "Javascript is disabled!" then you'll need to allow your browser to use javascript.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>This is a Test</h1>

<script>

document.write("<p>I like to code</p>");
document.write("<p>I will succeed at coding</p>");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Seems to be running fine. Copy pasted same code